# Make Treeview using Bootstrap Treeview Ajax JQuery with PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, treeview

I'm using Bootstrap-Treeview but I'm not sure how to set the data into the Treeview using Ajax and PHP.

On the sever side , The php file is called: fetch_data.php and goes like this:

```
    <?php

     include('db.php');

         $parent_sponsor_id = 0;

         $query = $DBcon->query("SELECT * FROM sponsor_referrals");
         $result = $query->fetch_array();

         foreach($result as $row)
          {

            $data = get_node_data($parent_sponsor_id, $DBcon);
           }


         echo json_encode(array_values($data));

       function get_node_data($parent_sponsor_id, $DBcon)
       {
        $query2 = $DBcon->query("SELECT * FROM sponsor_referrals WHERE sponsorId = '".$parent_sponsor_id."'");

        $result2 = $query2->fetch_array();
        $output = array();
        foreach($result2 as $row)
        {
        $sub_array = array();
        $sub_array['text'] = $row['referredId'];
        $sub_array['nodes'] = array_values(get_node_data($row['referredId'], $DBcon));
        $output[] = $sub_array;
        }
       return $output;
      }

      ?>
```

The script is this:

```
       fill_treeview();

      function fill_treeview()
      {

        $.ajax({
       url:"fetch_data.php",
      dataType:"json",
       success:function(data){

        $('#treeview').treeview({
         color: "#008cff",  
         nodeIcon: "fa fa-user",
         showTags: true,     
         data:data
          });
       }
     })
    }
```

I need help getting the treeview to work! thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the php code for this one, that works

```
   <?php

require 'db.php';

$parentKey = '0';

$sql = "SELECT * FROM sponsor_referrals";

$result = $DBcon->query($sql);

  if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)

  {

      $data = membersTree($parentKey);

  }else{

      $data=["id"=>"0","name"=>"No Members present in list","text"=>"No Members is present in list","nodes"=>[]];

  }



  function membersTree($parentKey)

  {

      global $DBcon;

      $row1 = array();

      $sql = 'SELECT id,referredId from sponsor_referrals WHERE sponsorId="'.$parentKey.'"';

      $result = $DBcon->query($sql);

      while($value = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){

         $id = $value['id'];

         $row1[$id]['id'] = $value['referredId'];

        $row1[$id]['name'] = $value['name'];

         $row1[$id]['text'] = $value['name'];
         $row1[$id]['nodes'] = array_values(membersTree($value['referredId']));

      }

      return $row1;

  }



  echo json_encode(array_values($data));



    ?>
```